# Getting only the first element from the list, how we can move to the second element of the list in java

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have this code, it return for me the 2 emails. The result look like this: [email1, email2]

```
public List<UserDto> getEmail() {
    
    Connection connection = null;
    
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    
    ResultSet searchResultSet = null;
    
    try {
    
        connection = getConnection();
    
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(
                        "SELECT EMAIL FROM USER WHERE USER.U_SEQ IN ('1','650')");
                
        searchResultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    
        return getEmail(searchResultSet);
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            preparedStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}


private List<UserDto> getEmail(ResultSet searchResultSet) throws SQLException {
    List<UserDto> result = new ArrayList<UserDto >();

    UserDto userDto = null;
  
    while (searchResultSet.next()) {
        userDto = new UserDto();

        userDto .setEmailAddress(searchResultSet.getString(1));
        result.add(userDto);
       
     }
     return result;
}
```

In the second class, I'm calling this method getEmail(), I want to send for first email then the second, but what I have here in the below code is only get i =0 always and it dose not go to the second email to send an email:

```
Delegate delegate = new Delegate();

    List<UserDto> users = iimDelegate.getEmail();
            for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++) {

                String ToEmail = users.get(i).toString();

                delegate.sendNotification("****", "****", toEmail , "", "",
                   "", body);
            }
```

Any help!

Comment: So does `List<UserDto>` only contain 1 element and has a size of 1, or does your List contain multiple elements but all have the same email address?

Comment: @OH GOD SPIDERS List<UserDto> have 2 different elements (different emails), all recipients (users) have same content of the email. currently it send only for i=0 which is the first email address.

Comment: Try to add 2 prints. The 1st one just before the sendNotification and the 2nd after the sendNotification. Print only email addresses. In case that you get 2 prints (emails) the problem is located at the method sendNotification OR the email is incorrect from your database. BTW, you should consider to change your connection structure. You are not closing the connection and the ResultSet. Just to remind you, these classes are auto-closeable, which means you can use the try-with-resources (java8+)

Comment: @Melron
How I can add 2 prints? if you trace the code inside the for loop, supposed when the i increment the email address will change which is moving to the next element. Also when I print the value of i, it shows i=0 then i=1 and also the email address change but it send only one email for the first email address.

Comment: @uma So, since you already used the 'print debug' thing and you got 2 different emails (inside of your loop), your problem is NOT the list or the size of the list. It is just located in the sendNotification OR (again) the email address is incorrect (doesn't exists?).

Answer (score 0):

Is this query correct?
`"SELECT EMAIL FROM USER WHERE USER.U_SEQ IN ('1','650')")`? Is it return the list of emails?

Comment: This could be a comment